# Arrays in Javascript and using chart.js

Tags: javascript, arrays, chart.js

I'm attempting to display a number of different datasets on a line graph using [chart.js](http://www.chartjs.org/).

Currently, if the number of data points/dates are the same for each dataset, the graph gets drawn correctly.

sample data:

```
30/09/2015 - Capital One - 200
31/10/2015 - Capital One - 150
30/11/2015 - Capital One - 140
30/09/2015 - Cash - 500
31/10/2015 - Cash - 240
30/11/2015 - Cash - 50
30/09/2015 - Natwest - 50
31/10/2015 - Natwest - 100
30/11/2015 - Natwest - 500
```

This produces the following graph:

[image]

However, if the number of data points/dates don't correspond for each dataset, e.g. Natwest below.

```
30/09/2015 - Capital One - 200
31/10/2015 - Capital One - 150
30/11/2015 - Capital One - 140
30/09/2015 - Cash - 500
31/10/2015 - Cash - 240
30/11/2015 - Cash - 50
31/10/2015 - Natwest - 100
30/11/2015 - Natwest - 500
30/12/2015 - Natwest - 50
```

Produces the following graph which is completely incorrect.

[image]

I believe the issue is that in the code below, the `data.labels` array should be the same length as the `chartjs_balances.data` array (`balances` variable) and if there isn't a balance for the corresponding date in `data.labels`, the `chartjs_balances.data` array (`balances` variable) should contain a null value.

currently:

```
data.labels = [30/09/2015, 31/10/2015, 30/11/2015, 30/12/2015]
data.datasets[0].data = [500.00, 240.00, 50.00]
data.datasets[1].data = [200.00, 150.00, 140.00]
data.datasets[2].data = [100.00, 500.00, 50.00]
```

I think it should be:

```
data.labels = [30/09/2015, 31/10/2015, 30/11/2015, 30/12/2015]
data.datasets[0].data = [500.00, 240.00, 50.00, null]
data.datasets[1].data = [200.00, 150.00, 140.00, null]
data.datasets[2].data = [null, 100.00, 500.00, 50.00]
```

However, I'm struggling to do this in Javascript. How can I achieve this?

Javascript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var balancesSortByAccId = gon.balancesSortByAccId;

var data = {
    labels: [],
    datasets: []
};

//loop through all accounts to generate datasets
for(var account in gon.balancesSortByAccId){
  var balances = [];
  var dates = [];

  var accountData = gon.balancesSortByAccId[account];

  for (var i in accountData) {
    balances.push(parseFloat(accountData[i].balance).toFixed(2)); 
    dates.push(convertDate(accountData[i].date));

    for (var date in dates)
      if (data.labels.indexOf(dates[date]) <= -1)
        data.labels.push(dates[date]);
  }

  var colour = getRandomColor();

  var chartjs_balances =           {
              label: account,
              fillColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.2)",
              strokeColor: colour,
              pointColor: colour,
              pointStrokeColor: colour,
              pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
              pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
              data: balances
          };


  data.datasets.push(chartjs_balances);
}

var options = {
  responsive: true,
  tooltipTemplate: "<%=label%>: £<%= value %>",
  multiTooltipTemplate: "<%=datasetLabel%>: £<%= value %>",
  showTooltips: true,
};

//draw graph
var ctx = document.getElementById("history_canvas").getContext("2d");
var myLineChart = new Chart(ctx).Line(data, options);

//convert date to dd/mm/yyyy format
function convertDate(inputFormat) {
  function pad(s) { return (s < 10) ? '0' + s : s; }
  var d = new Date(inputFormat);
  return [pad(d.getDate()), pad(d.getMonth()+1), d.getFullYear()].join('/');
}

//return random color for each dataset
function getRandomColor() {
    var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF'.split('');
    var color = '#';
    for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++ ) {
        color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
    }
    return color;
}

</script>
```

UPDATE:

gon.balancesSortByAccId format:

[image]

Where gon.balancesSortByAccId is set in a controller:

```
  def index
    @balances = Balance.all.order(date: :desc)

    @balancesSortedByAccountId = Hash[
      Balance.joins(:account).order(date: :asc).group_by(&:account_id).map{|acc_id, acc_details|
        [acc_details.first.account.name, acc_details.map(&:attributes)]
      }
    ]

    gon.balancesSortByAccId = @balancesSortedByAccountId
  end
```

Comment: What is the format of the raw data?

Comment: @MatthewHerbst I've updated the OP with the format and how the raw data is defined.